# Best way to place hard coded link in template in multi lingual drupal 8

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

My website (drupal 8) was first in one language. Now I switched to multi langual.

Most of the settings i did find (translate content, webforms, strings,...).

But at the moment stuck on the hard coded links I use in the template (theming).

So I'm looking for the best way to let my hard coded links work for more languages.

At this moment this is what i got (and ofcourse this is not working well):

```
<h4><a href="/node/100">{{ 'DIENSTEN ON SITE'|t }}</a></h4>
```

This link doesn't bring the visitor to the correct link (en/ or fr/ is missing). Translate on the string works already :).

My current settings for detections are visible in the image:
[image: So first selection is on url/prefix]

Thanks for reading!

Kristof

Answer (score 1):

For translated links you can use the [path function](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#path)

```
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': '100'}) }}"> {{ 'DIENSTEN ON SITE'|t }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a route name and parameters to generate the url. In Twig for example with [path()](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#path):

```
{# Link to node page. #}
<a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}">{{ 'View node page'|t }}</a>
```

Then outbound path processing can apply the configured language detection methods.

Comment: Thanks. But where should i fill in the node ID? I try this <h4><a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'/node/100': node.id}) }}">{{ 'DIENSTEN ON SITE'|t }}</a></h4> ... But this broke the site.. :)

Comment: Don't change `'node'`, this is the required parameter name. Put the node ID after the colon (replace `node.id`). You might want to enable error reporting (/admin/config/development/logging) so that you see what breaks your site.